# Mongodb remove field from Array objects all documents?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework

I have a collection that has documents looks something like this:

```js
{
  _id : 21353456,
  product : "xy",
  text : "asdf",
  reviews : [
    {
       username : "User1",
       userID: 12
       text : "hi",
     },
     {
       username : "User2",
       userID: 123
       text : "hi1",
     }
   ]
}
```

I want to remove the field in username from the objects in this array.
I tried this
db.collection.update({}, {$unset: {"reviews.username": 1}}, {multi: true})
I tried with even updateMany and it just matchedCouunt and acknowledged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the positional identifier and do something like:

```
db.collection.update({}, {$unset: {"reviews.$[].username":true}}, {multi:true})
```

Personally I prefer using the method below:

```
db.collection.update({"reviews.username": {$exists: true}}, {$unset: {"reviews.$.username":true}}, {multi:true})
```

Because sometimes you should check if it exists before you do the deleting (this way you won't get any errors).